# compilation failed for gmock expect_call for a function that takes lambda as an argument

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I am writing unit tests for my class using gtest/gmock. The compilation of unit test code fails.

mock declaration is

```
MOCK_METHOD2(GetFilesFromDirectory, std::shared_ptr<std::list<WIN32_FIND_DATAW>>(const std::wstring &directory, std::function<bool(const WIN32_FIND_DATAW &)> filter));
```

Then I write an EXPECT_CALL for this method in other method's test case as below and the compilation fails.

```
std::function<bool(const WIN32_FIND_DATAW &)> filesFilter = [](const WIN32_FIND_DATAW &fileData) -> bool {
    return true;
};

EXPECT_CALL(*mock, GetFilesFromDirectory(std::wstring(L"testDirectory"), filesFilter)).WillOnce(Return(fileListPtr));
```

The error I get is

**Error C2678   binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::function' (or there is no acceptable conversion)**

I would like to know why this error occurs and how I can fix this.

Comment: `std::function` doesn't have operator == to compare with other `std::function`.

Comment: correct. but how do I workaround this?

Comment: Do you really need to check for equality? `EXPECT_CALL(*mock, GetFilesFromDirectory(_, _)).WillOnce(::testing::ReturnArg<1>())` might do the job.

Comment: No, I don't want to check the equality and it worked...!. Thanks...:)